# Blur page background on button Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, blur

I have been looking for a solution that will blur the CSS3 background I have in place when the user clicks a button.

At the moment the HTML is as so:

```
<div class="button">
    <li><a href="#" alt="fade button">Start Now</a></li>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
html, body { margin:0px; padding: 0px; background: url(../assets/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;  -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover;  -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;}

.button { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:150px; 
    margin: 0 auto;  
    margin-top:200px;
    background-color:#81DF7B;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#333;
    font-weight:300;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.button:hover{ 
    background-color: #00CC33; 
    cursor:pointer;
}

.button li {padding:20px; text-align:center; text-decoration: none; list-style: none; }
.button li a {text-decoration: none;}
```

As you can see the background image is attached to html and body as a CSS3 cover image.

What I would like is when the user clicks on the 'Start Now' button this background transitions smoothly to a blur so that hidden form fields can appear over the top clearly.

I have been looking at blur.js and Jquery blur but can't work out the best way to implement this.

Any advice would be much appreciated :)

Comment: -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could implement css such as this for an onclick event for that button.

```
.background {     

-webkit-filter: blur(10px);     

filter: blur(10px);      

}
```